# barcode reader in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

HI,
I have used barcode reader in iPhone and its working but i want to display 
the barcode after scanning in given UITextField or UILabel in iPhone, i am anable to 
do it please help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks
Kunal

Comment: Hi, could you share your scanning code with us?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you'll need a barcode font, set the font and then draw the barcode "string" using that font. And only do this on iOS which allows custom fonts.

Comment: Actually my barcode reader is working properly and also display the information about the barcode... but I want to save that information in iPhone app... please help me about that problem

Comment: need to know more to help you.  barcode reader sends what it reads to the app in what form?  what barcode reader are you using?  This question doesn't have enough information to help you.